# How can I add a character counter to my Quill project?

Tags: javascript, html, quill

So I had to make a Quill interface for an asignmment. There must be a counter for words but I've found out that I also need a counter for all characters.
So what's the best way to add this character counter to my project.

```
    class Counter {
      constructor(quill, options) {
        this.quill = quill;
        this.options = options;
        this.container = document.querySelector(options.container);
        quill.on('text-change', this.update.bind(this));
        this.update();  // Account for initial contents
      }

      calculate() {
        let text = this.quill.getText();
        if (this.options.unit === 'word') {
          text = text.trim();
          // Splitting empty text returns a non-empty array
          return text.length > 0 ? text.split(/\s+/).length : 0;
        } else {
          return text.length;
        }
      }

      update() {
        var length = this.calculate();
        var label = this.options.unit;
        if (length !== 1) {
          label += 's';
        }
        this.container.innerText = length + ' ' + label;
      }
    }

    Quill.register('modules/counter', Counter);

    var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
      modules: {
        toolbar: toolbarOptions,
        counter: {
          container: '#counter',
          unit: 'word'
        }
      },
        theme: 'snow'
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The guide has a tutorial for writing a module that counts words or characters based on config option:
https://quilljs.com/guides/building-a-custom-module/#using-options

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    counter: {
      container: '#counter',
      unit: 'character'
    }
  }
});
```

Demo:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vPRoor

Answer (score 0):

In the example, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vPRoor.

The character count starts with 1 by default. Instead, it should start with 0. This can be done by adding trim method in calculate function.

Change:

```
calculate() {
let text = this.quill.getText();
```

To:

```
 calculate() {
 let text = this.quill.getText().trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
quill.on('text-change', function () {

    const limted = 10;
    const totalChar = quillEditor.getLength() - 1;

    if (quillEditor.getLength() > limted + 1)
        quillEditor.deleteText(limted, totalChar);
    else
        chCounter.text(totalChar)
});
```